# Composite indexing and normal indexing is not used

Tags: mysql

The indexing given for table is not working and the sql query creating deadlock.please help me in this.

The sql query:

```
UPDATE APA_Pended_Demand 
SET APA_Pended_Demand.genericDemandId=( 
    SELECT APA_Generic_Demand_Details.genericDemandId  
    FROM APA_Generic_Demand_Details  
    WHERE APA_Generic_Demand_Details.demandID=APA_Pended_Demand.demandID  
    AND APA_Pended_Demand.isPend = 1 
    AND APA_Generic_Demand_Details.genericDemandId != ''  
    AND APA_Generic_Demand_Details.genericDemandId IS NOT NULL  
    AND APA_Pended_Demand.reactivateDate > UTC_TIMESTAMP()
    AND APA_Generic_Demand_Details.status < 300
    AND APA_Pended_Demand.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
```

The indexing is:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `apgnricdmnddetils_prdcttype` (`productType`),
 KEY `apgnricdmnddtils_srcereqrle` (`sourceReqRole`),
 KEY `apgnericdemnddetils_methdin` (`methodIn`),
 KEY `apgnricdemnddetils_bndnresn` (`abandonReason`),
 KEY `IX1_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`customerReference`,`policyNo`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX2_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`schemeReference`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX3_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`aggregationKey`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX4_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`initiator`,`aggregationKey`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX5_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`policyNo`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX6_APA_Generic_Demand_Details_Status` (`status`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX7_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`genericDemandId`),
 KEY `IX8_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`initiator`,`status`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `status` (`status`),
 KEY `IX9_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`customerReference`,`status`) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `apgnericdemnddetils_methdin` FOREIGN KEY (`methodIn`) REFERENCES `APA_REF_CONTACT_METHOD` (`METHOD_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `apgnricdemnddetils_bndnresn` FOREIGN KEY (`abandonReason`) REFERENCES `APA_REF_ABANDON_REASON` (`REASON_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `apgnricdmnddetils_prdcttype` FOREIGN KEY (`productType`) REFERENCES `APA_REF_PRODUCT_TYPE` (`PRODUCTTYPE_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `apgnricdmnddtils_srcereqrle` FOREIGN KEY (`sourceReqRole`) REFERENCES `APA_REF_CUSTOMER_CONTACTS` (`CUSTOMER_CONTACT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14469 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Can anyone please answer my question